# Internationalization using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie to Angular JS. I've just started reading directives. I got my first task of Internationalization. I've gone through the docs of Angular JS i18n. They gave the very basic. Can any one suggest me a good example of creating the sample?

Thank you
Nizam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/)? It's easy to use.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('at', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(function ($translateProvider) {
  $translateProvider.translations('en', {
    TITLE: 'Hello',
    FOO: 'This is a paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'english',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'german'
  });
  $translateProvider.translations('de', {
    TITLE: 'Hallo',
    FOO: 'Dies ist ein Paragraph.',
    BUTTON_LANG_EN: 'englisch',
    BUTTON_LANG_DE: 'deutsch'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
  $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.uses(key);
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2>{{'TITLE' | translate}}</h2>
```

Then, you can call 'changeLanguage' to change other language.

```
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('en')">EN</button>
<button ng-click="changeLanguage('de')">DE</button>
```

[This](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide) is the guide.

Comment: ,Can you give me the example along with html as well?

Comment: What do we need to install? What are the JS needed? Plz let me know soon

Comment: angular-translate, I has been given the link at first line:) http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/

Comment: Helped that a lot. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

We used this simple [jQuery plugin](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/), wrapped in service and directive:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]);



app.service('i18n', function($q, $locale) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    jQuery.i18n.properties({
        name:'Messages', 
        path:'messages/', 
        mode : 'both',
        language:$locale.id, 
        callback: function() {
            deferred.resolve();
        } 

    });

    this.resolve = deferred.promise;

    this.getResource = function(key) {
        return jQuery.i18n.prop(key);
    };

});


app.directive('localize', function(i18n) {
    return {
        scope : {
            key : '=localize'
        },
        link : function($scope, $element, $attr) {
            $scope.$watch('key', function(key) {
                var value = i18n.getResource(key);
                $element.text(value);
            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I've used Jquery plugin  before. Thank you for your answer. But, I'm going to work on Angular JS like. I need to use Angular Translate.